# How can I partially read 2d satellite file in Python? (binary, fromfile)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, binary, fromfile

I have a lot of satellite data that is consists of two-dimension.

(I convert H5 to 2d array data that not include latitude information
 I made Lat/Lon information data additionally.)

I know real Lat/Lon coordination and **grid coordination** in one data.

**How can I partially read 2d satellite file in Python?**

"numpy.fromfile" was usually used to read binary file.

if I use option as count in numpy.fromfile, I can read binary file partially.

However I want to skip front records in one data for **save memory**.

for example, i have 3x3 2d data as follow:

> **python**
>
> a= [[1,2,3]
>       [4,5,6]
>       [7,8,9]]

I just read a[3][0] in Python. (result = 7)

When I read file in Fortran, I used "recl, rec".

> **Fortran**
>
> open(1, file='exsmaple.bin', access='direct', recl=4)   ! recl=4 means 4 btype
>
> read(1, rec=lat*x-lon) filename
>
> close(1)

lat means position of latitude in data.
(lat = 3 in above exsample ; start number is 1 in Fortran.)

lon means position of longitude in data.
(lon = 1 in above exsample ; start number is 1 in Fortran.)

x is no. rows.
(x = 3, above example, array is 3x3)

I can read file, and use only 4 byte of memory.

I want to know similar method in Python.

Please give me special information to save time and memory.

Thank you for reading my question.

**2016.10.28.
Solution**

> **python**
>   Data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], dtype = int8, filename=name
>
> a = np.memmap(name, dtype='int8', mode='r', shape=(1), offset=6)
>
> print a[0]
>
> result : **7**

Comment: Which type of file is it ? .h5 ? .nc ? .xml ?

Comment: First, it is H5 data. I convert H5 to just 2d array data (float32).

Comment: Thank you for reading my question and kindly answers.

Answer (score 0):

To read .h5 files :

```
import h5py
ds = h5py.File(filename, "r")
variable = ds['variable_name']
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to follow your description.  Some proper code indentation would help over come your English language problems.

So you have data on a H5 file.  The simplest approach is to `h5py` to load it into a Python/numpy session, and select the necessary data from those arrays.

But it sounds as though you have written a portion of this data to a 'plain' binary file.  It might help to know how you did it.  Also in what way is this 2d?

`np.fromfile` reads a file as though it was 1d.  Can you read this file, up to some `count`?  And with a correct `dtype`?

`np.fromfile` accepts an open file.  So I think you can open the file, use `seek` to skip forward, and then read `count` items from there. But I haven't tested that idea.

Comment: thank you for your answer! I find the solution. I can extract value from array using "memmap".